# Confusion about non-English posts

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, declined-flags, review-suspension, english

I have a confusion about the non-English questions on Stack Overflow and really do not know how to handle them in review queues. I know the intention is to flag them, but it is still confusing.

I've reviewed around 300 posts and I did come across several non-English ones as well as some mixed languages questions. I did flag them, and all those flags have been reviewed and responded with "not enough evidence" because all the posts have been edited meanwhile.

At the last (Triage) review I did mark such a post (in German) with requires editing which was a test by the way, and I have been banned from the review queues for more than two months.

So what should be the final consensus about non-English posts?

- If they should be flagged, reviewers of the flag queues should be ore careful about the post history. A person flagging those should not be punished. Maybe there should be a special flag for non-English posts?
- If they should be re-edited, suggesting an edit should not be punished.

Comment: Flag them as Unclear (Needs details or clarity in the flagging menu)

Comment: You've only ever had two flags on non-English content declined. Both of these were declined because you raised custom mod flags (flag -> "in need of moderator intervention"). Non-English posts do not require moderator intervention. Instead, you should flag them with one of the standard "not suitable for this site" reasons. It seems you learned this from the declined flags already. You have had 2 such "unclear" flags "disputed" after community review, but neither of these were on questions that had ever been written in any language other than English. So I'm not sure what you're confused about.

Comment: The reason why your Triage review was wrong was because you picked "Requires Editing". The "Requires Editing" option means that *a regular community member* could edit the question to meet our requirements. That isn't the case for non-English posts. Those can *only* be edited by the original author, and that's not what "requires editing" means.

Comment: Thanks for the brief analysis @CodyGray. It did really help to understand the distinction between flags.

Comment: Sure thing. We really do need better guidance/UX surrounding Triage and, in particular, the "Requires Editing" button. That is something that the team is currently working on. You'll find plenty of discussion about that here on Meta by searching "requires editing". But I've already summarized what you need to know, which is that it is for questions with grammar errors, formatting issues, etc., which can be fixed by anyone. If the edit must come from the original asker (OP), then you should mark it as "unsalvageable" and raise a flag (e.g., "needs details or clarity").

Comment: If you have any doubt on what to do just hit the skip button.